# Wait for subscriber to exist?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like for one node to wait for a subscriber to a topic to exist before publishing to it.  Is there a straightforward way to do that in rclcpp?

I'm developing on rolling if that matters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391602/wait-for-subscriber-to-exist?/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2021-11-25**:
I think @Geoff's answer suffices for your purpose, but FYI there are `wait_for_[publishers/subscribers]` methods in the RCL layer (refer to https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/907/). It would be nice if there were client library (rclcpp/rclpy) wrappers because that fits your use case exactly!

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-11-25**:
Some advice: in a robust **distributed** design, there are almost no good reasons a publishing node needs to know the number of subscribers. Remember you don't control who connects, and message delivery is unreliable. How does your node use this information?

**Comment by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on 2022-03-02**:
The original reason for this was to recreate the behavior of latched topics.  I've found another way to do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest method I can think of off the top of my head is to check the publisher's [`get_subscription_count()` method](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1PublisherBase.html#a60c84260b2ff0fb364fad688ed91234f) before publishing, and skip publishing (or even preparing to publish) if the count is zero. You might also need to check `get_intra_process_subscription_count()` as well.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1